# Is MISRA-C applicable to Linux applications

Tags: c, embedded, embedded-linux, misra

I understand that MISRA-C standards are intended for embedded *firmware*. When embedded Linux is your product platform, can/should your embedded applications be developed to be MISRA-C compliant? Has anyone ever considered such an exercise?

My general sense is that you must first understand all the 'rules' and then apply them in your design/coding phase. There may be instances like system calls (pthread_create) and void* that need to be forced into compliance - producing ugly looking code.

Comment: As per the document title, MISRA-C applies to all *critical systems* - and can be used for any applications beyond that scope.  Your approach to some of the rules (especially the advisories) may be more relaxed if used on non-embedded code.

Answer (score 5):

In a word: No.

MISRA does provide some good guidelines, but you'd be better off just cherry picking rules to which you want to adhere (assuming you have automated checking in your build / static analysis).

Skimming through MISRA-2004 stuff, here are some problem areas.

Having all your libraries be MISRA compliant is, in itself, MISRA rule.

Rules on `goto`, `continue` and `break`, function returns, and pointer arithmetic are violated in literally billions of lines of both kernel and userspace code, so good luck getting your libraries (or kernel) under compliance.

Pointer casting rules will be impossible to follow if using sockets, among other common APIs.

> MISRA-2004 11.2 Conversions shall not be performed between a pointer to object and any
>   type other than an integral type, another pointer to object type or a
>   pointer to void.

2004-20.x sections ban `<errno.h>`, `<stdio.h>`, `<time.h>` and `<signal.h>`.  Banning signals and error checking promotes BAD Linux programming if you're writing long-running, robust services.

And no dynamic memory allocation is a rule in there somewhere.

I know MISRA has rules that allow you to violate rules if you document them (is this true for *required* or just *advisory*???), but you'll document soooo many exceptions that it's really sort of pointless.

All that said, if you have a customer insisting on MISRA compliance (which is the only reason I've ever seen it used), you could probably document all your rule violations and make some hand-wavy attempt to call yourself MISRA compliant.  So there might be a business case for pretending to be MISRA compliant on Linux, but I see little to no technical advantage in it.

I'm afraid if you want to be *truly* compliant AND need a heavyweight/full-featured OS you're better off forking out the dough for QNX, GHS Integrity, VxWorks, etc.

Comment: Whether or not the libraries must be MISRA compliant is kind of debated. Because you'll find sloppily written libraries everywhere, and not just in the Linux source. That's why I think it is fine to ignore the libraries if the OP just wants MISRA-C to improve their own code. Linux programmers in general would benefit from adopting MISRA, or a subset of MISRA, so that they may learn what a real coding standard might look like. Instead of thinking that the hobbyist-level "Linux kernal style guide" is some sort of canon for good programming practice even outside the kernel project.

Comment: The reason you usually have to use MISRA-C is not because of "customers" however, but because you have to conform with industry safety standards for safety-critical applications. IEC 61508 (industry/generic), ISO 26262 (automotive), DO-178 (avionics) and so on. These standards demand that you use a safer subset of the language, with static code analysis, leaving you with pretty much just MISRA-C and SPARK Ada to chose from. But given that at least 61508 and 26262 and all other SIL standards are mostly filled with nonsense, I suppose it might boil back to "customer insists" in the end :)

Comment: Most of the MISRA requirements are based around developing software that is as deterministic as possible under all operating conditions.  You don't use `malloc` for the same reason CAN, ARINC-428, and MIL-STD-1553 are (typically) synchronous (compared with inherently async would of IP).  Determinism.  Guaranteeing deterministic performance is of paramount concern in hard realtime systems (particularly mission or safety critical ones), but often *detrimental* to overall system performance and therefore doesn't belong in a general purpose OS.

Comment: If you're trying to make certifiably MISRA-compliant software for Linux, you either don't understand the underpinnings of the standard or have a customer that doesn't.

That said, Linux is perfectly suitable to a wide range of non-safety critical embedded systems where some (often unknown) rate of failure due to over-subscribing your memory or dropping on a bus, etc, etc is acceptable.

Also, generally speaking, Linux userspace code *is* atrocious and could benefit from following more rigorous programming practices, I just think MISRA is not the answer.

Answer (score 4):

While MISRA-C was originally created as a standard just for automotive and safety-critical applications, this is no longer true. Nowadays MISRA-C is more of a general standard that can be used for any C programs where bugs, crashes and portability issues are not desired.

You need to ask yourself why you are using MISRA-C. Is it because you wish to use it as a coding standard to get rid of bugs, or because the application is of a mission-critical nature?

For the Linux case, the main issue will be if you'll just have your own code MISRA compliant, or if you will demand that this is true for all libraries included as well. And there is just no way you'll make the Linux kernel + libraries MISRA compliant, you'd have to rewrite Linux from scratch.

This makes Linux unsuitable for mission-critical software. But if your program is not of a mission-critical nature, you should be able to use Linux. You might have to write a number of standing deviations from MISRA-C in advance, for things that you can tell will cause problems.